# Header not redirect to .plist file

Tags: php, ios, iphone

Following is php code for redirect script to other page.

```
header("Location: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.abcd.com/buildmanagment/uploads/builds/63/Liberta_Place_1449744266/Liberta_Place_1449744266.plist");
```

It will not redirect to .plist file. I'm getting **Internal Server Error**

[image]